# General Sprinkler questions welcome here?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question came up today](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/498/leaking-near-top-valve-of-sprinkler-system-area). I mentioned the author might be better served on the DIY site as its more of a plumbing question than anything else. Should we welcome general sprinkler system questions or should we push them towards DIY? I realize this would be directly related to the care and maintenance of a garden/landscape, but it is truly a plumbing question is it not?

Answer (score 7):

I think water is pretty essential to a healthy garden and wells, pumps, pipes and hoses could be considered as tools like shovels and forks. I would wish to see this type of question allowed in gardening.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't disagree that water is essential to gardening. I welcome questions on quantity of water needed. How to best water. How to position your sprinkler well. Even the previous sprinkler question here on Meta about pests eating a sprinkler system is a good on topic question. However, the line has to be somewhere. I feel like that line is at repair. Ultimately this is about fixing a plumbing problem. Its tangentially related to gardening, but when push comes to shove its about pipes not plants.

Answer (score 6):

This is definitely a plumbing question.  In my opinion, it is related to gardening...but getting a response from gardeners in this realm gives you no unique insight that a plumber would not have.  In fact, a DIY plumber would be much more qualified to help you than a gardener.  I think that question should be closed as an off topic question.

Answer (score 2):

The question fails my (unofficial) [criterion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/where-are-the-boundaries-on-topic-vs-off-topic/60#60) at point #3.  It's only tangentially related to gardening and could find answers at the DIY site.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is interesting to fans of gardening because leakage of watering system are so common, however, the question will get better answer in DIY.

My opinion is to collect some sample answer of such question from DIY (if any exists), and post them in the FAQ of our site.