# Should questions tagged [sprinkler-system] or [sod] be migrated from Home Improvement?

Tags: discussion, migration

We currently have 17 questions tagged [sprinkler-system](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprinkler-system) on Home Improvement.

We also have 4 questions tagged [sod](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sod) (though there is some overlap).

Would any (all?) of these be suitable for Gardening & Landscaping?

Should we migrate these as a matter of course?

Answer (score 6):

We have only one question tagged [sprinkler-system](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sprinkler-system) here, and it's on preventing garden critters from chewing up sprinkler valves. Since (garden) pest control is right up our alley, it was [decided that such questions are on-topic](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/is-a-sprinkler-pest-question-on-topic).

However, most of the questions tagged `sprinkler-system` on DIY are related to plumbing issues and are off-topic here. [This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6992/leaking-sprinkler-system-area-top-of-valve) on DIY was simultaneously [cross-posted here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/498/leaking-near-top-valve-of-sprinkler-system-area) (now deleted by owner) and while it got an answer within 2 hours on DIY, it didn't attract any on G&L and was closed a day later. In [this discussion](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105/general-sprinkler-questions-welcome-here), although a "consensus" wasn't reached, the general opinion was that this is either off-topic or maybeish, but better off at DIY.

[This question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6143/how-often-long-should-i-water-my-lawn-with-new-sod) though, is very much on-topic and would be a good fit here. This is also one of the 4 tagged `sod`. Of the other three, [these](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2282/are-there-other-advantages-to-using-sod-over-grass-seed-besides-getting-instant-r) [two](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2129/drought-resistant-lawn-sod-recommendation-for-area-above-septic) are on-topic here. The former has a well upvoted accepted answer so, I think it's best to leave it there. We can take the latter, as the answer is not really an answer and might have a better chance of being answered here.

Comment: OK - I've looked and they're all quite old questions. I think they might be better left where they are. New questions I'll migrate.

Answer (score 6):

Generally I think these types of question are good for this site. Yoda's answer goes into more detail.

Main reason for this answer, though, is to point out that [sod](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sod) is a terrible tag from a British English point of view. I had to guess at its meaning and double check with Google. It just looks agricultural at best; at worst it looks like a joke tag. [turf](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turf) is used in UK English (& elsewhere?).

If [turf](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/turf) is even half-way understood by North Americans it would be a much better tag/master tag for this type of question.

Comment: Good point about the [sod]/[turf] meaning. I'll have to check the questions on DIY to make sure they're properly tagged before migrating

Comment: Sounds like a good candidate for a synonym (assuming there are actually any questions...) Sod is the common US term for both the turf and the activity of laying it, but turf should be reasonably familiar as well (though it has its own alternate meanings).