# Are backyard chickens and other pet / fowl / livestock on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Animals can be an important component of a sustainable food production system. However it is not clear from the faq if they are on topic here. Other than many questions related to manure, I found only [this](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/where-are-the-boundaries-on-topic-vs-off-topic) mention of livestock in meta.

Are Chickens and other livestock on or off topic here?

Answer (score 10):

There's a bunch of symbiotic relationships between animals and plants which are relevant to gardening and I don't think we should be too strict about banning these. So, for instance, a question like "how do I know if my chook is broody?" should not be allowed, but "what are the advantages of chooks in my garden?" should be totally okay.

Same goes for questions about breeding up spiders to patrol your fruit trees!

So, I'd say YES they are on topic in as much as they relate to some aspect of gardening but NO if not. This should be simple to patrol.

Answer (score 8):

I'd love to have a place to ask some of the "crossover" questions:

- Brush removal using goats.
- Use of blood/offal from butchering as fertilizer, or composting the same.
- Plant selection for stock-proof hedgerow to contain goats and horses.
- Maintenance of pastures.
- Grazing sheep & chickens on fallow garden space.

As it stands, I'm not sure if these would be on-topic in the (still very preliminary) Animal Husbandry proposal.

Still, just because your question *mentions* animals doesn't make it off topic. I asked a question about pasture maintenance in the context of treating it like a large lawn, and got a good answer. We've had a number of manure questions. If your question is more about gardening than about animals, I'd encourage you to ask it or drop into chat and propose a question. (The worst that happens is it gets closed.)

Comment: baaaaa... I think all your examples would be fine questions here (with the condition that pasture sizes are reasonable and don't require equipments out of an average person's reach). The key is that the question should be more about gardening than animals. My answer was specific to questions on animals only.

Answer (score 7):

One thing that ought to be on topic is the use of chickens hogs or goats for tilling your garden.

Comment: Also chickens as an "organic" pest control... If you have a major slug problem, get some chickens... I would have chickens in my garden if our sub-division bylaws allowed...

Answer (score 6):

Questions on chickens and all livestock are **off-topic** here. From the first line of the FAQ,

> Gardening and Landscaping - Stack Exchange is for **gardeners and landscapers**.

So this is not a sustainable food production Q&A, but a gardening & landscaping one. While it is true that some aspects of gardening overlaps with food production, livestock clearly falls under animal husbandry, not gardening.

There is a [proposal for animal husbandry on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/32167/animal-husbandry) that is suited to your needs. It is still in its "Definition" phase and has quite a long way to go before it gets through this one and the "Commitment" phase to launch into "Beta". However, you can take the initiative to spread the word among people who might be interested and participate in voting questions and helping the proposal move forward.

Until then, there is no site on the SE network where such questions can be asked. Sorry, but thanks for asking it on meta first :)